# Gauss elimination with constraints for variable's domain

Tags: linear-algebra, gaussian-elimination

Consider the following homogeneous, underdetermined linear system of equations:

$$
\begin{align}
c + d &= k + l \\
j + k &= c + d \\
i + l &= a + b
\end{align}
$$

As it stands (assuming e.g. $a,b,c,d,i,j,k,l \in \mathbb{R}$), this could easily be transformed into the standard $Ax = 0$ form with $A$ being the coefficient matrix and $x$ being a solution for this system. Then, we could simply use Gauss elimination to solve this system.

However, in reality, I have the additional constraint that $a,b,c,d,i,j,k,l \in \{+1,-1\}$, which will obviously reduce the amount of suitable solutions of the above system. My question is, whether there is a good way to encode this additional constraint in e.g. a formula that can be directly considered while solving the system of equations rather than using the constraint in a second step to "screen" the solution space.

The obvious way to encode this constraint into an equation would be e.g. $a^2 = 1$, but this equation is no longer linear and therefore I would be leaving the well known realm of linear algebra for solving the resulting non-linear system of equations.

Therefore, my question is: is there a way to directly solve for the solutions that fulfill the additional constraint within the framework of linear algebra (e.g. by some clever adaptation of the Gauss algorithm)?

Note: I am looking for a way to solve this kind of system algorithmically, so my question is really aiming at "is there a standard algorithm that can solve this kind of system?".

Comment: @lonestudent I don't know what that is, but I guess yes.